# Non-monochromatic (multi-wavelength?) lasers

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, solid-state-physics, laser, photonics

I was recently doing some reading on lasers, and I came across the fact that truly monochromatic light is impossible, which then obviously implies that truly monochromatic lasers are impossible. But this leads me to wonder:

1. If truly monochromatic light is impossible, then how do we know (how can we predict) the wavelengths of light that a laser "of certain wavelength" will emit (that is, non-experimentally, of course)?
2. Related to the above, does there exist a way for us to manipulate/build a laser so that it emits certain desired combinations of wavelengths, and perhaps in certain desired proportions, rather than just some combination as determined by nature?

Related to 2, it would be really nice if anyone knows of any resources/research related to technology such as what I've described here (multi-wavelength lasers?). I would really like to read about this more.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! You write: "White light is a phenomenon that helps us conceptualize this." What do you mean by this?

Comment: @descheleschilder Well, white light actually consists of multiple wavelengths of light, does it not?

Comment: Of course, but what are you trying to conceptualize?

Comment: @descheleschilder oh, just the fact that light can indeed consist of multiple wavelengths. White light is a common example of this fact, right?

Comment: Right! But how does the concept of white light is connected to laser light? Just because white light consists of different wavelengths? White light is not similar to laser light though.

Comment: @descheleschilder You're right. I guess I should have said that it's a loose analogy; not a very good one. Maybe I'll just edit it out.

Comment: Okidokiokidokio! (I have to submit at least 15 characters)

Comment: [Argon laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_laser#Argon_laser) emits multiple wavelengths simultaneously

Comment: @Ruslan Interesting. Can you build a laser that emits certain proportions of wavelengths that you're interested in? Do you know of any research that focuses on these types of lasers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of answers to your question here and to write them all would take some time, but I'll try to answer some of them briefly and enough to satisfy the topic.

When a laser is marketed as a $x$nm laser it is centered around that wavelength, with a (most likely) symmetric spectrum around this point. To understand where the *linewidth*, as the width of the emission peak is referred to as, comes from we need to go through some simple quantum physics.

A laser functions through exciting electrons in a 2, 3, 4 or even higher level system, where they will eventually fall down to lower energy states. If these electrons are stimulated enough, there will be more electrons in higher states than in lower states. This means that if we insert some seed photons into this element, they will stimulate emission from this *gain medium*, and the emission will be larger than the absorption. This is the condition for lasing, that the gain overcomes the losses.

The electrons are said to be in energy states, and in quantum mechanics these energy levels are split into even finer energy levels centered around that one level. Thus, the electron can have a number of different, however close, energy levels. This means that electrons of not just one wavelength are being stimulated.

This is oe source of the finite linewidth of the laser. Another source which may *limit* the linewidth is the cavity making up the laser. I will not go into the makings of a laser in detail here and all the equations but the design of the cavity affects the linewidth as well as the *gain profile* of the laser medium.

Lastly, a laser linewidth can be affected by the environment. Atoms and molecules at higher temperatures for example broadens the distribution of wavelengths on each energy level and thus thi will also broaden the linewidth of the laser. Some external sources for this broadening is referred to as *natural-*, *Doppler-* and *pressure*-broadening.

With all this said, it is possible to design a laser given some spectral specifications. The center wavelength can be chosen if a lasing medium exists for this wavelength, linewidth can be tuned. Something i did not go over in this text here is transverse and longitudinal laser modes, but essentially even a laser linewidth is made up of even finer linewidths making up the complete linewidth.

I've not yet heard of a laser with more than one center wavelength. Modelocked lasers are laser with extremely broad linewidths where the modes in the lasers are locked with regards to each other and thus they create a pulsed behaviour with the energy contained.

Comment: _"I've not yet heard of a laser with more than one center wavelength"_ — apparently, [argon laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_laser#Argon_laser) has (or can have) such a feature.

Comment: @Ruslan I only skimmed through that now but I saw nothing about it lasing at more than one center wavelength at a time? Surely a lot of gain mediums have several lasing wavelengths, the design of the laser selects which one will be used (choice of pump laser, cavity design etc).

Comment: In the page I linked to there's a photo with the description _"An argon-laser beam consisting of multiple colors (wavelengths) strikes a silicon diffraction mirror grating and is separated into several beams"_.

Comment: @Ruslan wow! I yield

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_laser_types) article different types of lasers are to be seen. The wavelengths are **not** exact. This is impossible since then you would need a resonator cave of infinite length.
The wavelength can theoretically be determined. See how this is done [here](https://endurancelasers.com/some-calculations-about-laser-power-impulse-wavelength-energy/)

The answer to your second point can be found [here](https://www.photontec-berlin.com/multi_wavelength_laser_system.html). If I understand your second point correctly.